# How can this pdf file be created from this website?

Tags: pdf, web

[This pdf file](https://vowi.fsinf.at/images/d/d7/TU_Wien-Grundlagen_der_Programmkonstruktion_VU_%28Puntigam%29_-_How_to_design_programs_-_An_Introduction_to_computing_and_programming_%28free_webversion%29.pdf) seems created from [this site](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/).

I check the information of the pdf file by `pdfinfo` the pdf file:

```
Creator:        pdftk 1.12 - www.pdftk.com
Producer:       itext-paulo (lowagie.com)[JDK1.1] - build 132
CreationDate:   Mon Mar 20 14:07:22 2006
ModDate:        Mon Mar 20 14:07:22 2006
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          565
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      6657623 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

I don't know pdftk can create pdf files from webpages. I guess it was created by some other way (which can add number to left bottom of each page), and then processed by pdftk. But I am happy to be wrong.

I like to know how that can be created (so long ago), because I would like to have a pdf file from [the newer version of the book](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/).

Comment: They probably just used pdftk to glue some pages together or something.

Comment: I guess so, but the number of each page? Eventually I want to download their second edition. :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is:

1. Print each section as `pdf` and then crop the unnecessary parts (like the navigation "buttons") with `pdfcrop`
2. Use `pdfpages` package in latex and insert the pages of the previously printed and corpped files. You can add any type of header/footer/page number this way.

Comment: Thanks. can we write a script to automate the process, given there are many pages?

Comment: @Tim Yes you can, but it will not be fully automated. You can use `xdotool mousemove x_cord y_xord click 1` and `xdotool getmouselocation` to make the clicks for printing the webpage to PDF. Then you will arrange the pdfcrop margins manually for the first section/chapter/document and replicate the process for the rest of the sections/pdf files. Finally, you can consult http://texblog.org/tag/pdfpages/ to merge the pages with the `pdfpages` package. If you want to reset the page number you can consult http://texblog.org/2007/07/25/counters-in-latex/ to use `\setcounter{page}{#number}`